# Como faço para quando passar o mouse em cima de uma determinada div, aparecer outro elemento?

Tags: jquery, css

Meu objetivo é ter uma div invisível, e quando passar o mouse em cima dessa div invisivel, fazer aparecer uma outra div?

exemplo:

```
<div class="invisivel"></div>
<div class=visivel">
  Olá
</div>
```

Comment: Se tens uma _div invisível_ como é que o utilizador sabe que está em cima dela? Queres dizer que tens 2 divs invisíveis? Explica melhor para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Isso, inicialmente ambas vão estar invisiveis, mas quando passar o mouse na div 1, vai ficar visivel a div 2

Comment: Mas podes explicar mais sobre o HTML e como/onde queres usar isso? saber mais sobre o problema leva à solução certa.

Comment: Isa: a solução que melhor resolve o teu problema és tu quem melhor sabe. Vi que aceitaste uma resposta. Mas como não descreveste o problema tens menos respostas e possivelmente desadequadas ao teu caso. Se o teu caso for HTML como indicaste o melhor então é usar só CSS. Sem JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que descrição do seu problema está errada.

De qualquer forma, é só usar o método `show()` do jQuery dentro de um evento de `mouseOver`.

```js
$('.visivel').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.invisivel').show();
});

$('.visivel').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.invisivel').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="visivel">
  Olá
</div>

<div class="invisivel" style="display:none">
  Invisivel
</div>
```

Comment: Vc consegue adaptar esse exemplo pra quando eu tirar o mouse de cima sumir novamente?

Comment: Sim, @Isa. Veja a edição.

Comment: Segundo comentários na pergunta _"inicialmente ambas vão estar invisiveis"_... vamos esperar por mais informação/descrição.